# Page reload when clicking a button Javascript, HTML

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, function, button

I have an issue when clicking a button. My page reload and the message "MERCI, VEUILLEZ VÉRIFIER VOS MESSAGES" doesn't display. I don't know if these two issues are linked. I'm on Wordpress, Chrome, with DIVI themes. and I don't have error in console.

HTML:

```
<form class="formnumber">
  <input class="inputsms" id="number" placeholder="ENTREZ VOTRE NUMÉRO" />
  <button class="buttonsms" id="buttonsms">ENVOYER ></button>
</form>
```

JavaScript:

```
var button = document.getElementById('buttonsms');


if(button){
button.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  this.classList.add('is-done');

  setTimeout(function() {
    button.innerHTML = "MERCI, VEUILLEZ VÉRIFIER VOS MESSAGES "
  }, 500);
});
}
```

You can see all the code with CSS and animation [here](https://jsfiddle.net/JorisP/k5nafeeo/1/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

easy, set the button attribute to be onmousedown="location.reload();"

Comment: the full html would look like <button onmousedown="location.reload()">Reload</button>

Comment: and to get the message to pop up. call a another function within the onmousedown attribute that alerts the user of your message.                   ex: <button onmousedown="location.reload(); alertUser();">Reload</button>                                                                             where the function looks like                                                                               alertUser(){alert("message you want here");}

Comment: does that help?

Comment: in your code it will look like this <button class="buttonsms" id="buttonsms" onmousedown="location.reload(); alertUser();">ENVOYER ></button> with the javascript function mentioned above inside a <script> tag

Comment: Can you say me where to put it in my code please ? I put it in the HTML like this:
<form class="formnumber">
  <input class="inputsms" id="number" placeholder="ENTREZ VOTRE NUMÉRO" />
  <button onmousedown="location.reload()" class="buttonsms" id="buttonsms">ENVOYER ></button>
</form>

But not working :)

Comment: I just did above. make sure that the alertUser() function is inside the <script> tag like this                                                      
<script>alertUser(){alert("message you want here");} </script>                              and the button I put above, so copy that and what I just wrote here and put that into your html

Comment: ok I see the problem. the button is in a form, that's is why it is reloading. take the location.reload(); out of the button and move the button outside of the form

Comment: And is it possible to put it in the form cause I have a CSS depending on that (I edit message with CSS)

Comment: I changed the html of it and it had a css animation where the message opened up to the left and it was cool. is this what you are looking for?

Comment: Yes that's it :)

Comment: awesome. it looks great. just move the button outside of the form like this. <form class="formnumber">
  <input class="inputsms" id="number" placeholder="ENTREZ VOTRE NUMÉRO" />
</form>
<button class="buttonsms" id="buttonsms">ENVOYER ></button>

Comment: Yes but the style is not the same, I commented with pictures

Comment: where are the pictures?

Comment: I replied with the images, I don't know how to comment with images.

Comment: that's very weird I got the animations that you wanted when I ran it. I'm sorry, I wish I could help you but unfortunately I think I've done all I can. If you need anything else, just ask because I'm not even sure what to do

Answer (score 0):

When I replace the HTML by

```
    <form class="formnumber"> 
<input class="inputsms" id="number" placeholder="ENTREZ VOTRE NUMÉRO" /> </form> 
<button class="buttonsms" id="buttonsms">ENVOYER ></button>
```

Animation and style before replacing:

[image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/916nw.png)
[image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PQZRC.png)

Animation and style after replacing:

[image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3eH4q.png)
[image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P3gin.png)